# Send signal to process under debug with GDB DSF in Eclipse CDT (Juno)

Tags: eclipse, gdb, eclipse-cdt

Can somebody please explain how to send a signal to a process being debugged under Eclipse CDT  using GDB (DSF)? Apparently the Signals view in Eclipse (Junon) is no longer used, and I'm fairly inexperienced in debugging with Eclipse + CDT.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you could try is, find the id of the process from a terminal window, using `ps -ef`. Then use the `kill` command to send the signal from the terminal window, eg. `kill -2 <id>` will send a SIGINT to the process.